# Run a function on each item in parallel every 5 seconds with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am processing a video and want to check multiple regions of interest in parallel, every 5 seconds. I would like to know if the function I currently have is accomplishing this in the correct manner.

```
def checkFrames():
    timer = threading.Timer(5.0, checkFrames)
    timer.daemon = True
    timer.start()
    if(started):
        index = 0
        for region in regions:
            threading.Thread(target=processRegion, args=(frame, region, index)).start()
            index += 1
```

Right now I can't really tell if all of the regions are being processed in parallel (although I know that they are all being processed). The program runs pretty slow here compared to when I'm purposely checking the regions right after the other. The processing for all the regions don't have to start at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this code appears to launch N threads in parallel every 5 seconds, however, it may perform no faster than a single thread that examines N regions, due to Python's [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: Would changing my function to spawn multiple processes instead of threads make sense to do if this were the problem?

Comment: Yes.  Look at Python's multiprocessing library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

You are currently creating 6 new threads for each iteration (1 `checkFrames` and 5 `processRegion`). Creating a threads is time and resources consuming. What I suggest is to create 5 threads that will process each every 5 seconds

```
def checkFrame(frame, region, index):
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        processRegion(frame, region ,index)
        sleep(5 - time.time() - start_time)
for region in len(regions):
    threading.Thread(target=checkFrame, args=(frame, region, index)).start()
```

This code assumes that a `processRegion` call takes under 5 seconds.